# logged in user gets redirected to Login page on refresh React JS & firebase V9

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm working on an application where I want a dashboard and all pages to be accessible to a user with a role of admin and another page to a logged in user with a role of employee. If the employee attempts to access the dashboard via the URL, he should be redirected to the login page. This seems to work fine. My issue is that if I refresh the home page, I am redirected to the login page. I think this is due to the time it takes for `auth` to load the user.I've tried applying localStorage or firebase setPersistence() but so far I have not managed to fix the problem.

I think the problem originates from the code in **UserAuthContext.js**

```
const userAuthContext = createContext()

export function UserAuthContextProvider({ children }) {

  const [user, setUser] = useState({})

function logIn(email, password) {
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
   
  }

useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      
        setUser(user)
   
    })
    return () => {
      unsubscribe()
    }
  }, [])

  return <userAuthContext.Provider value={{ user, signUp, logIn, logOut }}>{children}</userAuthContext.Provider>
}

export function useUserAuth() {
  return useContext(userAuthContext)
}
```

**App.js** where I first compare the logged in user's email with the emails of admin users from a `firestore` collection

```
const { user } = useUserAuth()
 
  const [adminUsers, setAdminUsers] = useState([])
  const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useState(false)
  

  useEffect(() => {
    getAdmins()
  }, [])

  const getAdmins = async () => {
    const data = await PrivateUserDataService.getAdminUsers()
    setAdminUsers(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })))

  }

  const adminsArray = []

  adminUsers.map((admin) => {
    adminsArray.push(admin.email)

  })

  useEffect(() => {
    
    const adminEmail = adminsArray.find(v => v.includes(user.email))

    if (adminEmail === user.email) {
      setIsAdmin(true)
    }
  },[])

  return (

    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
    
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/">
            <Route index element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="home" element={<ProtectedRoute isAdmin={isAdmin}><Home /> </ProtectedRoute>} />
           <Route path="rapport_passage" element={<ProtectedRoute isAdmin={isAdmin}><RapportPassage /></ProtectedRoute>} />
         </Route>
        </Routes>
        
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );

}

export default App;
```

**ProtectedRoute.js** receives a true or false isAdmin prop from the App

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ children,isAdmin }) => {

        let { user } = useUserAuth()
    
        if (!user || isAdmin === false) {
            return <Navigate to='/' />
    
        }
       
        else {
    
            return children
    
        }
        
    }
    
    export default ProtectedRoute
```